# How can I change the backgound image of a specific Vaadin view to be an image?

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a view in Vaadin like so...

```
public class PosAppPickerView extends VerticalLayout implements View {
```

Everything is working great but I want to add an image as a background for the body/main panel.

How can I do this?  This is the only page with this custom background.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to define the background image in that view via SASS / CSS and just add the classname to that PosAppPickerView class.